# How to transfer vertex colors (features) to texture map (UV Space) using pytorch3d?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch3d

Suppose I know the following information:

1. vertices, faces and
2. uv and uv_faces and vertex colors (features)

How can I render/interpolate vertex colors (features) to a texture map? Such as,

[image]